# Regular Expression for Wright Express?

Tags: regex

There is plenty of info available about regular expressions for credit card numbers (for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html). However I have not been able to find info on the regular expression (or any other description) for the number used by Wright Express (which I think is some kind of fuel card). Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: What's the syntax for Wright Express card numbers?

Comment: Looks like the answer below found the syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their examples on their website, such a number looks like `0400 00 123456 7`. To check this format with a regular expression, you could use

```
"\d{4} \d{2} \d{6} \d"
```

Comment: I was unable to find number information on their website. Can you add a comment with the URL that will lead me to the info? Thx

Comment: I found this here: http://www.wrightexpress.com/Cards/card-products2.htm. Not sure if this is the card you need. I have never heard of this company before, being from Germany.. =)